# Windows says Temporary Profile on Login

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Logged on with a temporary profile](https://superuser.com/questions/279770/windows-7-logged-on-with-a-temporary-profile)

I have this serious problem. Whenever I start windows, it says 'this is a temporary login profile. The files you create and update in this profile will be deleted when you log off'.

I have only one login profile of which I am the administrator. All the software I add on login automatically gets deleted when I reboot the system. I am not able to find out whats the problem.

I dont have any other OS used in my system.

Comment: Please specify what version of Windows you're using :)

Comment: I'm using Windows7

Answer (score 1):

Which Windows operating system are you using?

*There's a guide for Windows 7 - also available here.*

Log in with your temporary profile.

Start Registry Editor by typing regedit in the Run dialog/Start Menu find box in Windows 7.

Navigate the following location in the Registry Editor:

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

You should be able to see many 'keys' - one with a .bak extension.

Your correct profile key is marked as .bak. Currently your Windows 7 computer is logged in with a fresh profile with the same key. So, rename the new profile key (which does not have the bak extension) and remove .bak from correct profile key. Image link below.

http://www.sysprobs.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/bakremoved.png

That’s it. Log off and log in with your user name and password. Some profile settings/icons might have been reset, although the profile should be working as normal.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.